# What is the difference between getData('tier_price') and getTierPrices() in configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, tiered-pricing

I have a configurable product with price, special price and tier prices.

I'm able to get the price, special price but not the tiered prices list.

All child products have the same price so instead of adding tiered price for each product, it will easier and faster to add them on the configurable product.

I'm having the following code in `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();

$_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();

var_dump( $_tierPrices );
```

This variable `$_tierPrices` will return an empty array. However if I replace `getTierPrices()` with `getDate('tier_price')` I'll get all the tier prices that are associated with the configurable product.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();

$_tierPrices = $_product->getData('tier_price');

var_dump( $_tierPrices ); // print each tier price as array
```

So what make `getData()` return prices and `getTierPrices()` returns nothing?

**Note:** this happens with configurable products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why `getTierPrices()` was not return anything for configurable products with tier pricing.

This extension [Simple Configurable Products](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) is altering configurable tier pricing to return empty array.

In order to fix this issue go to this class `OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price` in the following file:

> app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php

And remove or comment this function:

```
public function getTierPrice($qty=null, $product)
{
    return array();
}
```